# New to Exceptions

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the exceptions, but I got an error

```
import sys

while True:
        try:
            horas = int(input("¿Cuántas horas trabajó por semana? "))
            except TypeError as exception:
                print("Solo números enteros")
                return horas
```

```
except TypeError, e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `except TypeError as e:`. You appear to be using very old Python-2 syntax with Python 3.

Comment: You also have indentation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is improper indentation. The `try` and `except` statements need to be at the same indentation level. Also, your return statement should only be inside the try statement. If an exception occurs, the variable `horas` will not be initialized and therefore would throw a different error. You also don't want your return statement to be called until a user successfully inputs the correct type, so you shouldn't place the return statement after the `try/except` statement

Here is an example of how to fix your current code:

```
import sys

while True: 
     try: 
         horas = int(input("¿Cuántas horas trabajó por semana? ")) 
         return horas
     except TypeError as e: 
         print("Solo números enteros")
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix the indentation

```
import sys


def get_horas():
    while True: 
         try: 
             horas = int(input("¿Cuántas horas trabajó por semana? ")) 
             return horas
         except TypeError as exception: 
             print("Solo números enteros")          

get_horas()
```

Comment: now it says this:

return horas
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: To solve that, you should put your logic into a function `def my_function_name()` or omit the `return` and display or otherwise use your variable!